# How to use GraphElementData's predefined shapes with the old syntax?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider a simple graph as follows:

```
edges={
    {"vertex0"->"vertex1","1"},
    {"vertex0"->"vertex2","2"},

    {"vertex1"->"vertex3","3"},
    {"vertex2"->"vertex4","4"},

    {"vertex1"->"vertex5","3"},
    {"vertex5"->"vertex6","4"}
};

LayeredGraphPlot[
    edges,Left,

    EdgeShapeFunction->GraphElementData[{"ShortFilledArrow"}] (* syntax 1 *)
    EdgeShapeFunction->({Black,Arrowheads[{{0.04,0.5}}],If[MemberQ[{"vertex5"},Last@#2],Line,Arrow][#1]}&) (* syntax 2 *),
]
```

Both syntax for defining `EdgeShapeFunction` are correct. The first one uses a predefined `GraphElementData` to get a predefined shape for `ArrowHeads` but the second syntax allow more specification for controlling the `Edges` based on `Vertex` values.

My question is how do I use the predefined `GraphElementData` in the second syntax? I tried to do the following but it doesn't work.

```
EdgeShapeFunction->({Black,Arrowheads[{{0.04,0.5,GraphElementData[{"ShortFilledArrow"}]}}],If[MemberQ[{"vertex5"},Last@#2],Line,Arrow][#1]}&)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(This answer is basically the same as @kglr's, but avoids post-processing and includes a discovery mechanism.)*

You can use the "Options" discovery mechanism to find out the options supported by a particular graph element:

```
GraphElementData["ShortFilledArrow", "Options"]
```

> {"ArrowSize" -> Automatic, "ArrowPositions" -> Automatic}

Your desired [`Arrowheads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads) spec:

```
GraphElementData[
    {"ShortFilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .04, "ArrowPositions"->.5}
][{{0,0}, {1,1}}, 1 <-> 2] //InputForm
```

> {Arrowheads[{{0.04, 0.5, {Graphics[FilledCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, 
>          {{{-0.6666528591843921, -0.3333333333333333}, {-0.533327810340424, 
>             6.903741136987662*^-6}, {-0.6666528591843921, 0.3333333333333333}, 
>            {0., 6.903741136987662*^-6}}}]], 0.533327810340424}}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}

Creating a graph with the above shape function:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[
    edges,
    Left,
    EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData[
        {"ShortFilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .05, "ArrowPositions"->.5}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Modifying the shape function to include directives and other logic:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[
    edges,
    Left,
    EdgeShapeFunction -> Function @ {
        Black,
        If[#2[[2]] === "vertex5",
            Line[#1],
            GraphElementData[{"ShortFilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .04, "ArrowPositions"->.5}][##]
        ]
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the discovery mechanism `GraphElementData[..., "Options"]`. How did you find it? I don't see it in the documentation or maybe it slipped my eye. I have been trying `GraphElementData[..., "Properties"]` which is the discovery mechanism for `EntityFramework` but it gives something else here.

Comment: I noticed `GraphElementData` is gone in version 13.2 ...

Answer (score 2):

```
LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Black, If[MemberQ[{"vertex5"}, Last@#2], Line@#, 
    GraphElementData[{"ShortFilledArrow"}][##]]} &)]
```

[image]

To change the size and/or position of the arrow glyph you can use:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Black, If[MemberQ[{"vertex5"}, Last@#2], Line@#, 
   GraphElementData[{"ShortFilledArrow"}][##] /.
     Arrowheads[{{_, _, a_}}] :> Arrowheads[{{.04, .5, a}}]]} &)]
```

[image]

Change the replacement rule to `Arrowheads[{{_, _, a_}}] :> Arrowheads[{{.1, .5, a}}]` to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your trick is very useful when one doesn't know the discovery mechanism. But since I can only select one answer I will choose Carl's since it gives the discovery mechanism but upvote for you too!